# How do I access Images folder in the controller in the current development server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My development server is called the WebApp which has the following folders as shown in the image. I want to write a method/function to access the 'Images' folder inside the controller while the application is running

[image]

Comment: That's not a server. That's your project, inside your solution. your server (assuming what VS is giving you) is IIS Express. Also you cannot modify a .net application while it's running as it compiles and then runs

Comment: I think you need something like `Server.MapPath("~/Images/")`

Comment: @Jabberwocky when this application is run locally the WebApp folder will become a development server.

Comment: @SahilTiwari not quite...the code gets compiled into a subfolder within your project directory and _that_ is what is served via IIS express. But actually I'm not sure this is relevant....I don't think you are literally talking about changing the code while the app is running? I suspect kristech's solution is more like what you are asking about (i.e. how to construct a relative file path correctly)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the path to the folder and then can access each file in the folder. Try this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles();

foreach(FileInfo file in files)
{
    string fileName = file.Name;
}
```